# I made a claim against my previous employer underpaying me. Now they threaten my career. [UK]

Tags: communication, united-kingdom, email, unprofessional-behavior, employer

I handed in my resignation to my old employer on May the 8th. I started my new job on June the 11th. Later in June, I received a letter saying they won't be paying me. I argued it and it's not an argument of if a policy existed before I handed my resignation in. My most recent e-mail from them has a paragraph that sounds like a threat to my new job. It says this:

> You work in a regulated sector and your behavior while employed at
>   *Censored* may return to your detriment as it may damage your ability to continue working in the education sector, you should be careful
>   with how you approach any challenge and be measured in what you do.

To me this seems borderline illegal. I'm looking at a legal battle with the employer anyway. Is this something I can use to their detriment?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace,GDavies. *"Is this something I can use to their detriment?"* This is something you should ask a lawyer, we do not offer legal advice here.

Comment: @GDavies You may consider asking this on [law.stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/). I would provide more context: *a)* are you asking if they have legal grounds to withhold payment of a salary, that in your view, you are due for the time before leaving? *b)* what's the context of *any challenge,* reference as in *legal challenge* or *professional challenge?* Why they would care if you are careful / *measured* or not? The question needs more context to clarify what's the actual issue.

Comment: Of course, this can be used to their detriment. It's retaliation for wanting to get paid. In any case, you should contact a lawyer, or the government agency, where you file your claim. But first, you'll have to formally file your claim, I would think, but I'm not a lawyer. Just don't tell them what you're going to do before you do it.

Comment: Also, never talk to your employer directly. Don't pick up if they call. If they continue to make threats, you want them to be recorded in your voicemail, or in writing. Also, they're less likely to make huge threats if they know they're being recorded.

Comment: As you're in the UK, I recommend an appointment with the Citizens' Advice Bureau. Take along a copy of any documentation you have (emails, employment contract etc). The CAB offers excellent employment law adivce, free of charge.

Comment: Any employment lawyer would love to see this letter. There’s nothing that a lawyer loves more than an opponent who is nasty and stupid.